# CData and Escape characters in a C# Webservice Reference

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services, soap, cdata

I am trying to communicate with some thirdparty middleware Java webservice,
We send an XML over Soap using a string, which causes the automagically generated visual bindings to replace some characters with escape characters

```
"&lt;" / "&gt;" / "&#xD;"
```

that for some reason the Java Webservice (soap host) can't deal with.

So the alternative to escaping illegal characters is wrapping everything in an

```
"<![CDATA[...]]",
```

however this doesn't stop the automatically generated bindings from escaping all special

```
(<, >, \)
```

characters.

So the result is something like this

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions how to approach this problem?

```
EndpointAddress = New System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(WebserviceReleaseURL)
serviceBinding = New System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding()
serviceBinding.ReceiveTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 120)

serviceBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport
serviceBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic

serviceBinding.MessageEncoding = System.ServiceModel.WSMessageEncoding.Mtom

serviceBinding.ProxyAddress = New Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8888")
serviceBinding.BypassProxyOnLocal = False
serviceBinding.UseDefaultWebProxy = False

c = New VU.receive_PortTypeClient(serviceBinding, endpointAddress)

c.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = WebserviceReleaseUsername
c.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = WebserviceReleasePassword
c.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation

c.Open()

Dim ServiceInput As New VU.receiveIn
Dim ServiceOutput As New VU.receiveOut

Dim cdata As New XCData(data)

ServiceInput.xmlString = cdata.ToString();
ServiceOutput = c.receive(ServiceInput)
```

Comment: the contents of CDATA is not part of the markup so whatever is included will appear as text. The predefined characters &lt etc are for use in markup. Within the CDATA you can just include < > etc.

Comment: The problem is that the bindings that visual studio generates, automatically escape < > /, i am trying to get control over it, so i can stop it from doing that inside CData blocks but i have no clue how.

Comment: you may need to simply string replace those characters (c#) eg data = data.Replace("&lt", "<").Replace("&gt", ">"); where data is a string

Comment: Thats the whole problem, before the request is send the characters internally get escaped, i have no control over it.